# Setting color/background for faded area while showing a (custom) dialog?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

Is it possible to change the default property of faded area color/background while showing a custom dialog.

I know for complete transparency in faded area. But want to change the color of it.

Comment: @saran, thanks for the reply. It contains styling only dialog window. I need for styling faded area when dialog displays.

Comment: That is for not fading background. I need to set my own background in that place with out fading it.